# SQL Subquery JOIN issue with Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, join

I'm stuck at understanding something melted between Laravel Query Builder and pure SQL I guess.

I have 2 tables :

- **User** : containing users with primary key `user_id`
- **User_Action** : which is a table containing records with composed PRIMARY KEYs of the `user_id` and the `datetime` of the action.

ex:

**user**

```
user_id
1
```

**user_action**

```
user_id    datetime              action_type
1          2017-12-01 12:10:00   y
1          2017-12-01 12:00:00   x
```

**My need** :

Now I want to retrieve a user list, with the newest action for each user. So I need to get only 1 row in the JOIN from `user` to `user_action`, and this row have to be the one with newest datetime.
So in my ex; I would like to get only the record with the datetime `2017-12-01 12:10:00` with a LEFT JOIN (to retrieve user even if there's no action).

I tried the following :

```
$userActionSubquery = DB::table('user_action')
        ->select()
        ->orderBy('datetime', 'DESC')
        ->limit(1);
$query->leftJoinSub($userActionSubquery, 'user_action', function ($join) {
         $join->on('user_action.user_id', '=', 'user.user_id');
})->groupBy('user_id');
```

By doing so, I'm not getting anything from `user_action` table, BUT it works if the action of the given user is the newest of the table !
I thought the `$join->on` would filter user id but the JOIN subquery is ran without this filter, and I can't but a WHERE in subquery because I don't have a user_id to give ! it's a query to get a list of user !

PS : the query generated is

```
SELECT user.user_id FROM user left join (SELECT * FROM user_action ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1) as user_action on user_action.user_id = user.user_id WHERE user.tenant_id in ('7') GROUP BY `user_id`
```

I'm missing something to succeed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sub = \DB::table('user_action')
    ->select([
        'user_id',
        \DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( action_type ORDER BY datetime DESC ), ",", 1 ) AS last_action_type')
    ])
    ->groupBy('user_id');

$data = \DB::table('user')
    ->leftJoinSub($sub, 'tmp', function ($join) {
        $join->on('tmp.user_id', '=', 'user.id');
    })->get();
```

sql:

```
SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( action_type ORDER BY datetime DESC ), ',', 1 ) AS last_action_type FROM user_action GROUP BY user_id ) AS tmp ON tmp.user_id = user.id
```

It works in my test env:

**user**

```
id   name
1    john
2    jack
```

**user_action**

```
id   user_id   datetime              action_type
1    1         2020-09-24 23:51:00   login
2    1         2020-09-24 23:51:20   search
3    2         2020-09-24 23:30:00   login
4    2         2020-09-25 00:00:00   coding
```

**result**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => john
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [last_action_type] => search
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => jack
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [last_action_type] => coding
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: thank you, the missing key here for me to fully understand what I was doing is to use an aggregate function into the subquery. I don't know why I was so lost at the time !

Comment: I did something similar than you, but I used rather select chaining syntax and MAX aggregation func : 
`$query->select('user_id')->selectRaw('MAX(datetime) as maxDatetime')->groupBy('user_id')`